# Sum of two sinusoidal function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I want to calculate the sum of this two functions

$$ y_1(t) = A_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 \cdot t)  $$
$$ y_2(t) = A_2 \cdot \sin(\omega_2 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2}) $$
What would be ?? $$ y = y_1 +y_2 $$

Comment: Umm... what about $$A_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 \cdot t)+A_2 \cdot \sin(\omega_2 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$$
????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is just $$y_1+y_2=A_1\cdot \sin( \omega_1\cdot t) + A_2\cdot \sin( \omega_2\cdot t+\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$$ You could also use $$\sin(t+\dfrac{\pi}{2})=\cos(t)$$ to get that $$y_1+y_2=A_1\cdot \sin( \omega_1\cdot t) + A_2\cdot \cos( \omega_2\cdot t).$$

Comment: but can that be written  under the form of $$ y(t) = A \cdot sin(\omega\cdot t + \varphi) $$

Comment: @CalinStefan Definitely not for every $A_1$, $A_2$, $\omega_1$, and $\omega_2$. It could be done with additional assumptions such as $A_1=A_2$ and $\omega_1=\omega_2$.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: $\sin(t+\frac{\pi}2)=\cos(t)$ there shouldn't be negative sign.

Comment: @Soheil True! Thanks for showing the  typo.

Comment: You're welcome!